# fineuploader demo i reacreated but does not show on browser

Tags: fine-uploader

hello i checked http://fineuploader.com/demos.html

and in 'Manually Trigger Uploads & Edit File Names'

i tried the code and recreate it on my pc

but i don't see anything in browser, just blank

here's the code(all the code in one html file only, github just cut the code here):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- jQuery
====================================================================== -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fine Uploader New/Modern CSS file
====================================================================== -->
<link href="css/fine-uploader-new.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Fine Uploader jQuery JS file
====================================================================== -->
<script src="js/jquery.fine-uploader.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fine Uploader Thumbnails template w/ customization
====================================================================== -->
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-manual-trigger">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Select files</div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="trigger-upload" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload
            </button>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" qq-server-scale>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Retry</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <input type="text">
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    </div>
</script>

<style>
    #trigger-upload {
        color: white;
        background-color: #00ABC7;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 7px 20px;
        background-image: none;
    }

    #fine-uploader-manual-trigger .qq-upload-button {
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    #fine-uploader-manual-trigger .buttons {
        width: 36%;
    }

    #fine-uploader-manual-trigger .qq-uploader .qq-total-progress-bar-container {
        width: 60%;
    }
</style>

<title>Fine Uploader Manual Upload Trigger Demo</title>



<!-- Fine Uploader DOM Element
====================================================================== -->

<!-- Your code to create an instance of Fine Uploader and bind to the DOM/template
====================================================================== -->
<script>
    $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger').fineUploader({
        template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
        request: {
            endpoint: '/server/uploads'
        },
        thumbnails: {
            placeholders: {
                waitingPath: '/source/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                notAvailablePath: '/source/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
            }
        },
        autoUpload: false
    });

    $('#trigger-upload').click(function() {
        $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger).fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i also have the js and css in the folders
how to make this work??? thanks

Comment: To run a web application, you must host the app on a web _server_. Simply placing files into folders is not sufficient. I suggest locating a web developer to help you out with this integration.

Comment: hello thanks for your reply. now, it's in a wamp server i'll check again...

Comment: Also check the browsers dev tools console and your server logs for clues.

Comment: thanks. but i can't see anything even the ui. i viewed using the server url... in the website demo section, does the sample code ("jquery version") really work? for one, this part is missing a quote in the selector area: 
            $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger).fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles'); - 'Manually Trigger Uploads & Edit File Names' section

Comment: hello again. the "no dependency" version worked while the jquery one i can't.. thanks